# How much battery power will my Arduino need?

Tags: arduino, batteries

So I am designing an arduino project that uses multiple devices.

GPS, NFC, IFR Temp gauge, and bluetooth trans.

The trick is though that it needs to be battery powered. I am a great programmer but I am just learning about circuitry and I have no clue how to determine how much power I will need.

Is there an easy way I can calculate which battery I will need?

Please use laymen s terms.

Comment: Plan A would be to identify the make and model of each item, find it's data sheet, look up power used by each item (at start-up, active, idle etc) add them up and from that work out what sort of current you need and decide how long you want to run it from batteries. From that you can find a suitable battery. Plan B would be to plug it into a bench supply and measure current draw under various conditions.

Comment: Thank you, can you make this an answer so I can upvote it and check it if no one else comes up with something better @RedGrittyBrick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plan A would be to identify the make and model of each item, find it's data sheet, look up power used by each item (at start-up, active, idle etc) add them up and from that work out what sort of current you need and decide how long you want to run it from batteries. From that you can find a suitable battery.

Plan B would be to plug it into a bench supply and measure current draw under various conditions.